# How to combine queries with a single external variable using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I am trying to accept a variable input of many search terms seperated by commas via html form (@search) and query 2 columns of a dataframe.

Each column query works on its own but I cannot get them to work together in a and/or way.

First column query:

```
filtered = df.query ('`Drug Name` in @search')
```

Second column query:

```
filtered = df.query ('BP.str.contains(@search, na=False)', engine='python')
```

**edit**
combining like this:

```
filtered = df.query ("('`Drug Name` in @search') and ('BP.str.contains(@search, na=False)', engine='python')")
```

Gives the following error, highlighting the python identifier in the engine argument

> SyntaxError: Python keyword not valid identifier in numexpr query

**edit 2**

The dataframe is read from an excel file, with columns:
Drug Name (containing a single drug name), BP, U&E (with long descriptive text entries)

The search terms will be input via html form:

```
search = request.values.get('searchinput').replace(" ","").split(',')
```

as a list of drugs which a patient may be on sometimes with the addition of specific conditions relating to medication use. sample user input:

> Captopril, Paracetamol, kidney disease, chronic

I want the list to be checked against specific drug names and also to check other columns such as BP and U&E for any mention of the search terms.

**edit 3**

Apologies, but trying to implement the answers given is giving me stacks of errors. What I have below is giving me 90% of what I'm after, letting me search both columns including the whole contents of 'BP'. But I can only search a single term via the terminal, if I # out and swap the lines which collect the use input (taking it from the html form as apposed to the terminal) I get:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

```
@app.route('/', methods=("POST", "GET"))

    def html_table():
        searchterms = []
        #searchterms = request.values.get('searchinput').replace(" ","").split(',')
        searchterms = input("Enter drug...")   
        filtered = df.query('`Drug Name` in @searchterms | BP.str.contains(@searchterms, na=False)', engine='python')
        return render_template('drugsafety.html', tables=[filtered.to_html(classes='data')], titles=['na', 'Drug List'])

<form action="" method="post">
  <p><label for="search">Search</label>
  <input type="text" name="searchinput"></p>        
  <p><input type="submit"></p>
</form>
```

**Sample data**

The contents of the BP column can be quite long, descriptive and variable but an example is:

> Every 12 months – Patients with CKD every 3 to 6 months.

```
Drug Name         BP                            U&E
Perindopril       Every 12 months               Not needed
Alendronic Acid   Not needed                    Every 12 months
Allopurinol       Whilst titrating - 3 months   Not needed
```

With this line:

```
searchterms = request.values.get('searchinput')
```

Entering 'months' into the html form outputs:

```
1   Perindopril  Every 12 months                Not needed 
14  Allopurinol  Whilst titrating – 3 months    Not needed
```

All good.

Entering 'Alendronic Acid' into the html form outputs:

```
13  Alendronic Acid Not needed  Every 12 months
```

Also good, but entering 'Perindopril, Allopurinol' returns nothing.

If I change the line to:

```
searchterms = request.values.get('searchinput').replace(" ","").split(',')
```

I get TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' when the page reloads.

However - If I then change:

```
filtered = df.query('`Drug Name` in @searchterms | BP.str.contains(@searchterms, na=False)', engine='python')
```

to:

```
filtered = df.query('`Drug Name` in @searchterms')
```

Then the unhashable type error goes and entering 'Perindopril, Allopurinol'
returns:

```
1   Perindopril   Every 12 months                   Not needed
14  Allopurinol   Whilst titrating – Every 3 months Not needed
```

But I'm now no longer searching the BP column for the searchterms.

Just thought that maybe its because searchterms is a list '[]' changed it t oa tuple '()' Didn't change anything.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: it could be just a posting mistake but the joined filtration has the `engine` keyword inside the query... (i.e. your `"` does not end in the correct place).

Comment: is it possible to get some  sample input data?

Comment: `.query` is too powerful and often the slowest function to perform this task. If I were you, I would use `sets intersection` to find out of values in X are in B. See my answer below.

Comment: @Dave could you provide a sample input, e.g. like this: `df = pd.DataFrame(data)` or just copy the first 10 rows of your dataframe here so we can copy paste it, it would also be helpful if you could provide your sample user input and what the expected output would be. Otherwise its more like guessing than helping.

Comment: @Dave do you want to search in all columns (Drug Name, BP and U&E), or only in Drug Name and BP? If all three, then searching for 'months' would return all 3 rows (since 'Alendronic Acid' has 'Every 12 months' in U&E), right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you want to query 2 columns and want to return the row if any of the query matches.

In this line, the issue is that engine=python is inside query.

```
filtered = df.query ("('`Drug Name` in @search') and ('BP.str.contains(@search, na=False)', engine='python')")
```

It should be

```
df.query("BP.str.contains(@search, na=False)", engine='python')
```

If you do `searchterms = request.values.get('searchinput').replace(" ","").split(',')`, it converts your string to list of words which will cause `Unhashable type list` error because str.contains expects str as input.

What you can do is use regex to search for search terms in list, it will look something like this:

```
df.query("BP.str.contains('|'.join(@search), na=False, regex=True)", engine='python')
```

What this does is it searches for all the individual words using regex. (`'|'.join(@search)` will be "searchterm_1|search_term2|..." and "|" is used to represent or in regex, so it looks for searchterm_1 or searchterm_2 in BP column value)

To combine the outputs of both queries, you can run those separately and concatenate the results

```
pd.concat([df.query("`Drug Name` in @search", engine='python'),df.query("BP.str.contains('|'.join(@search), na=False, regex=True)", engine='python')])
```

Also any string based matching will require your strings to match perfectly, including case. so you can maybe lowercase everything in dataframe and query. Similarly for space separated words, this will remove spaces.

if you do `searchterms = request.values.get('searchinput').replace(" ","").split(',')` on `Every 12 months`, it will get converted to "Every12months". so you can maybe remove the .replace() part and just use `searchterms = request.values.get('searchinput').split(',')`

Comment: That's fantastic, thanks very much! Appreciate the explanation of the unhashable type error too.

Answer (score 2):

Use `sets`. You can change the text columns to sets and check for intersection with the input. The rest is pure `pandas`. I never use `.query` because it is slow.

```
# change your search from list to set
search = set(request.values.get('searchinput').replace(" ","").split(','))

filtered = df.loc[(df['Drug Name'].str.split().map(lambda x: set(x).intersection(search)))
                  & (df['BP'].str.split().map(lambda x: set(x).intersection(search)))]

print(filtered)
```

Demo:

```
import pandas as pd

search = set(["apple", "banana", "orange"])
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Drug Name": ["I am eating an apple", "We are banana", "nothing is here"],
    "BP": ["apple is good", "nothing is here", "nothing is there"],
    "Just": [1, 2, 3]
})


filtered = df.loc[(df['Drug Name'].str.split().map(lambda x: set(x).intersection(search)))
                  & (df['BP'].str.split().map(lambda x: set(x).intersection(search)))]

print(filtered)

#               Drug Name             BP  Just
# 0  I am eating an apple  apple is good     1
```

### Updated:

> I would want the results to also show We are banana, nothing is here and 2

That requires `or` which is Pandas' `|` instead of `and` which Pandas' `$`

```py
filtered = df.loc[(df['Drug Name'].str.split().map(lambda x: set(x).intersection(search)))
                  | (df['BP'].str.split().map(lambda x: set(x).intersection(search)))]

print(filtered)

#                Drug Name               BP  Just
# 0  I am eating an apple    apple is good       1
# 1          We are banana   nothing is here     2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but if the user inputted apples, banana, oranges. I would want the results to also show We are banana, nothing is here and 2.

Comment: Then the condition is not `&` (and) but `|`(or). Change that and you will have second row too.

Comment: I have updated the answer to show the two differences

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search for text in all columns, you can first `join` all columns, and then check for search terms in each row using `str.contains` and the regular expression pattern that matches at least one of the terms (`term1|term2|...|termN`). I've also added `flags=re.IGNORECASE` to make the search case-insensitive:

```
# search function
def search(searchterms):
    return df.loc[df.apply(' '.join, axis=1)    # join text in all columns
        .str.contains(                          # check if it contains
            '|'.join([                          # regex pattern
                x.strip()                       # strip spaces
                for x in searchterms.split(',') # split by ','
            ]), flags=re.IGNORECASE)]           # case-insensitive

# test search terms
for s in ['Alendronic Acid', 'months', 'Perindopril, Allopurinol']:
    print(f'Search terms: "{s}"')
    print(search(s))
    print('-'*70)
```

Output:

```
Search terms: "Alendronic Acid"
         Drug Name          BP              U&E
1  Alendronic Acid  Not needed  Every 12 months
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Search terms: "months"
         Drug Name                           BP              U&E
0      Perindopril              Every 12 months       Not needed
1  Alendronic Acid                   Not needed  Every 12 months
2      Allopurinol  Whilst titrating - 3 months       Not needed
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Search terms: "Perindopril, Allopurinol"
     Drug Name                           BP         U&E
0  Perindopril              Every 12 months  Not needed
2  Allopurinol  Whilst titrating - 3 months  Not needed
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

P.S. If you want to limit search to specific columns, here's a version that does that (with the default of searching all columns for convenience):

```
# search function
def search(searchterms, cols=None):
    
    # search columns (if None, searches in all columns)
    if cols is None:
        cols = df.columns
        
    return df.loc[df[cols].apply(' '.join, axis=1) # join text in cols
        .str.contains(                             # check if it contains
            '|'.join([                             # regex pattern
                x.strip()                          # remove spaces
                for x in searchterms.split(',')    # split by ','
            ]), flags=re.IGNORECASE)]              # make search case-insensitive
```

Now if I search for `months` only in `Drug Name` and `BP`, it will not return `Alendronic Acid` where `months` is only found in `U&E`:

```
search('months', ['Drug Name', 'BP'])
```

Output:

```
     Drug Name                           BP         U&E
0  Perindopril              Every 12 months  Not needed
2  Allopurinol  Whilst titrating - 3 months  Not needed
```

Answer (score 1):

Without having sample input data, I used a random generated dataset as a showcase:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Drug_Name':['Drug1','Drug2','Drug3','Drug2','Drug5','Drug3']*4,
                  'Inv_Type': ['X', 'Y']*12,
                 'Quant': np.random.randint(2,20, size=24)})

# Search 1
search = "Drug3"
df.query('Drug_Name==@search')

# Search 2
search2 = "Y"
df.query ('Inv_Type.str.contains(@search2, na=False)', engine='python')

# Combined (use booleans, such as & or | instead of and or or
df.query ('Drug_Name==@search & Inv_Type.str.contains(@search2, na=False)')
```

Please note that `engine='python'` should be avoided as stated in the documentation:

> Likewise, you can pass `engine='python'` to evaluate an expression using
> Python itself as a backend. This is not recommended as it is
> inefficient compared to using numexpr as the engine.

That said, if you are hell-bent on using it, you can do it like this:

```
mask = df["Inv_Type"].str.contains(search2, na=False)
df.query('Drug_Name==@search & @mask')
```

Alternatvely, you can achive the same without using .query() at all:

```
df[(df['Drug_Name']==search) & df['Inv_Type'].str.contains(search2, na=False)]
```